# How can I add time series data into a range of time series list?

Tags: python, excel, indexing, time-series, addition

I have several spreadsheets with specific time series data. I want to summarize those specific times into a summary sheet with ranges of times.

for example: we have our summary date ranges

- `[Dec 21, Dec 22, Dec 23]` (midnight to midnight).

and the data would be something like this:

1. `Dec 21 10:00 = 15`
2. `Dec 21 11:00 = 10`
3. `Dec 22 13:00 = 5`
4. `Dec 22 16:00 = 10`
5. `Dec 23 2:00 = 6`
6. `Dec 23 12:00 = 6`

Thus I would like the summary to end up being: `Dec 21 = 25`, `Dec 22 = 15`, `Dec 23 = 12`.

I'm using python, datetime, and the openpyxl module to access and create time values.

I'm having a hard time getting my head around the creation of the time series list. as well as the actual addition.

getting the actual datetimes and values from the individual sheets is easy.

```py
for sheet in projectList:
    ws = wb[sheet]
    LOCSum = 0
    LOCList = {}
    for cols in range(8,30):
        LOCDate = ws.cell(row=4, column=cols).value #A datetime
        LOCSum = ws.cell(row=70, column=cols).value #A number
        LOCList = LocList + appendToListOfValues(LOCDate, LOCSum)
    fitListOfValuesIntoSummary(LOCList)
```

Once I've got `LOCDate` and `LOCSum`, how can I put them together into a list that can then be added to the summary? the `appendToListOfValues()` function that doesn't really exist. Should it be a dictionary? a Tuple?

then, once I've got a time series list, how do I make it fit into the summary list? the `fitListOfValuesIntoSummary()` function that also doesn't exist.

and the final kicker, what should I do if the data is outside the designated ranges? Do I just have it added to a "before" and "After" range for the summary list?

Please point me in the direction of some literature as well.

(As I've been typing up this question.)

Would just automatically adding the found value to the summary cell in the excel doc work?

```py
if LOCDate >= summaryDate+1:
    summaryDate = summaryDate+1
if summaryDate <= LOCDate <= summaryDate+1:
    ws[summary]['correctCol'+'correctRow'].value = ws[summary]['correctCol'+'correctRow'].value + LOCSum
```

Answer (score 0):

This ended up working for me.

```py
for sheet in projectList:
    ws = wb[sheet]
    LOCDate = 0
    LOCSum = 0
    weeklyLOCAvailCol = 7
    for cols in range(8,30):
        LOCDate = ws.cell(row=19, column=cols).value #a datetime
        LOCSum = ws.cell(row=70, column=cols).value #a number
        if LOCDate >= wb[summName].cell(row=4, column=weeklyLOCAvailCol+1).value: #check if the current values date is greater than the next slot.
            weeklyLOCAvailCol += 1 #if so, move up one slot.
        wb[summary].cell(row=LOCAvailpos, column=weeklyLOCAvailCol).value = wb[summary].cell(row=LOCAvailpos, column=weeklyLOCAvailCol).value + LOCSum
#then, add the current LOCSum value to whatever is in the current date range cell.
```

So what ends up happening is that each summary cell holds the current total of each individual sheet's cell.

`H70-J70` on each sheet is summed up in `H28` so long as `H70-J70` is less than the next time range's first datetime. and once it's found that `K70` is greater than `I28`'s datetime, then the next set is stored in `I28`

This isn't ideal as it requires an excel spreadsheet, but it slots data into a range. If there was a way to do this faster, I think that would help others.